# How do I checkout a GitHub project from command line as a Collaborator?

Tags: github, clone

This seems like a simple question which should have a simple answer...

I'm trying to checkout a GitHub project. The project is owned by someone else, so someone else is the *Owner*. GitHub *Collaborators* have read/write access, and I have been granted collaborator rights on the project. Collaborators are slightly different than *Contributors*, who have simply provided a pull request in the past.

I'm trying to avoid the following because I do not want the source files in "read-only" mode:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project.git
```

I feel like I need to identify myself, and send my password or SSH key. But GitHub's help at [Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) only discusses SSH in the context of a Desktop client. I guess they have an app they want me to use, but I don't really want to use one.

**Note**: I have information in Git's *global* config (`user.name` and `user.email`), but its not the correct information/credentials for these purposes.

How do I checkout a GitHub based project as a *Collaborator* from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Using the the HTTP endpoint instead of the the SSH one.

As an aside, when you say checkout do you mean clone, fork or pull?

for clone it would be similar to this:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/project.js.git
```

You will be prompted for your user name and password.

Comment: Thanks. I believe its clone. Git has really complicated the flows. So what used to mean "checkout" has other meanings in Git. This is what I am trying to avoid: `git clone https://github.com/user/project.js.git`. I do not identify myself, and I don't want to get stuck with a read-only copy of the source files.

Comment: Yes, in git Checkout is a way overwrite your local changes.  Clone is typically used to create a new folder with a clean copy of the project.  Pull is used to merge external changes with your local changes.  Coming from experience with SVN, VSS and PVCS it took me some getting used to the Git terminology and behavior.

Comment: "read-only" copy?  Please elaborate.  Git does not quite work like that. Once you clone, you are free to make change and then PUSH them back to the global repository.  Typically you would Fork, then clone to your desktop. Work with the code, push your changes back to your fork,  When ready you make a pull request to owner of the original project to integrate your changes.

Comment: *"When ready you make a pull request to owner of the original project to integrate your changes"* - I think that's the difference between GitHub's *Collaborators* and *Contributors*. Collaborators have read-write access; while contributors have read-only access. Collaborators don't need to wait for the *Owner* to take action - they can check-in directly.

Comment: Agreed. I believe that is the case.

Comment: OK, so the question is: how do I checkout from the command line as a collaborator so I have read-write access and can perform a checkin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79719/discussion-between-jeffrey-a-gochin-and-jww).